# Divisibility Problem (1328A) from Codeforces, I am getting the required output in visual studio but in codeforces the test cases are failing. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

[question - Divisibility Problem (1328A)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQJmw.png)

This is my Code

```
t = int(input())
lst = []
for i in range(0,t):
    nums = list(map(int,input().split()))
    result = (nums[0] % nums[-1])
    lst.append(result)
for i in range(0,len(lst)):
    print(lst[i])
```

[My visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v81vB.png)

[output in codeforce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH37g.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is flawed, you are finding the number of iterations where increasing `b` would result in divisibility between the numbers and the problem is asking you to increase `a` in every step.

Answer (score 0):

```
#1328A
user = int(input())
for i in range(user):
  n = int(input())
  m = int(input())
c = 0
if n%m==0:
  c = 0
else:
  c = 0
  b = True
  while b==True:
    if n>m*2:
      n= n-1
      c+=1
      if n%m == 0:
        b = False
    else:
      n= n+1
      c+=1
      if n%m == 0:
        b = False
print(c)
```

Comment: please add more explanation for others to understand your answer better

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).